# strange result in calculating the expectation drawing balls from a urn with replacement

Tags: probability

It is Question 6 on page 164 in Ross's book (Introduction to Probability Models-11th edition)

An urn contains 3 white, 6 red and 5 black balls. 6 of these balls are randomly selected from the urn with replacement. Let X and Y denote respectively the number of white and black balls selected. Compute $E[X|Y = 1]$.

Here is my steps:

Suppose Z denotes the number of red balls selected. With replacement, it follows a multinomial distribution,

$p_{X|Y}(X = 1|Y = 1)$

= $P(X=1,Y=1)$ / $P(Y=1)$

= $P(X = 1,Y = 1,Z = 4)$ / $P(Y = 1)$

= ${6\choose 1, 1, 4}$ $(\frac{3}{14})^1$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{6}{14})^4$ 
$/$ ${6\choose 1}$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{9}{14})^5$

= $80/243$

$p_{X|Y}(X = 2|Y = 1)$

= $P(X=2,Y=1)$ / $P(Y=1)$

= $P(X = 2,Y = 1,Z = 3)$ / $P(Y = 1)$

= ${6\choose 2, 1, 3}$ $(\frac{3}{14})^2$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{6}{14})^3$ 
$/$ ${6\choose 1}$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{9}{14})^5$

= $80/243$

$p_{X|Y}(X = 3|Y = 1)$

= $P(X=3,Y=1)$ / $P(Y=1)$

= $P(X = 3,Y = 1,Z = 2)$ / $P(Y = 1)$

= ${6\choose 3, 1, 2}$ $(\frac{3}{14})^3$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{6}{14})^2$ 
$/$ ${6\choose 1}$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{9}{14})^5$

= $40/243$

$p_{X|Y}(X = 0|Y = 1)$

= $P(X=0,Y = 1)$ / $P(Y=1)$

= $P(X = 0,Y = 1,Z = 5)$ / $P(Y = 1)$

= ${6\choose 0, 1, 5}$ $(\frac{3}{14})^0$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{6}{14})^5$ 
$/$ ${6\choose 1}$ $(\frac{5}{14})^1$ $(\frac{9}{14})^5$

= $32/243$

then I found

$p_{X|Y}(X = 1|Y = 1)$ + $p_{X|Y}(X = 2|Y = 1)$ + $p_{X|Y}(X = 3|Y = 1)$ + $p_{X|Y}(X = 0|Y = 1)$

=$80/243 + 80/243 + 40/243 + 32/243$

= $232/243$    < 1

I was stuck here. I think the above should add up to 1, but I am not sure where is wrong.

$E[X|Y]$ = $\sum_{x=0}^3 x p_{X|Y}(X|Y = 1)$

BTW,

$E[X|Y = 1]$ can be calculated as  $5 * 3/9$ = $5/3$

Thanks in advance. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Regardless of **with replacement** and **without replacement**, the expectation of $E[X|Y]$ is of the same if the number of balls selected is in a certain range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting with replacement you can get more than three white balls.  You can consider it five draws with $1/3$ chance of white and $2/3$ chance of red.  The chance of four whites is $5 \cdot (\frac 13)^4\cdot\frac 23=\frac {10}{243}$ and the chance of five whites is $(\frac 13)^5=\frac 1{243}$  This makes the sum of the probabilities come to $1$ as it should.

A simpler approach to get the expected number of white balls is to note that the expected number on each draw is $\frac 13$, so the expected total is $\frac 53$

Answer (score 2):

Your probabilities shouldn't add up to one, as you also need to consider the cases for $x=4$ and $x=5$, since $x$ should range from $0$ to $5$.

Comment: Thank you. I forget it is with replacement.